# Testing a website

Tags: php

I have some experience with HTML, CSS, and PHP but I have a question about my method for testing my code. basically the way we learned in class was that to test our PHP or SQL we would need to upload the code to the website. I doubt this is how most sites do their debugging as we would constantly see sites going down or having crazy errors.

I'm wondering if there is a way to test a website with php locally or what methods most professionally launched websites use to debug and test before updating the site with actual code.

Thank you!

Comment: This question is too broad. There are entire books written about this. There is also plenty of learning materials online. You just have to search it.

Comment: Versioning. Means that locally you test and resfresh and play, than after you're happy you submit your code version (AKA commit your changes). After all programmers are done with their versions and there's no bugs or collisions - than at some defined *nightly* time website is updated. That's only one way to do it... use Goog.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very broad question, but yes, it is unrealistic to run development code in a production environment. That's why you'll run into many paradigms, one of which is having a local, staging, and production environment.

If you want to test locally, you'll need to set up a local server in that case.

If you're using PHP and MySQL, you're probably using an Apache server.

Not sure which operating system you're running, but you may be looking for either a LAMP/MAMP tutorial (that is the stack: Linux or Mac, Apache, MySQL, PHP).

Just Google for it. Here's maybe a starting point:
[Installing MAMP web server](https://drupalize.me/videos/installing-mamp-web-server).

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I was looking for. I'm running Linux (Elementary OS) so I'll look into creating a local server for testing!

Comment: @Nickknack, no prob!

Answer (score 1):

In a professional setting, this testing would be done by extensive unit testing. The most elementary definition of that is, testing every method out of context to see if it reacts as expected in every possible scenario.

https://phpunit.de/ Here is a framework I found for unit testing in PHP. I hope it helps. My experience lies mostly in Java unit testing.

For clarification;
they would ofcourse have a seperate development environment where they could "play around" in.

Comment: I believe the OP's question is referring more to that of how to set up a testing environment, rather than unit testing itself.

Comment: @JoshBeam to me it looks like he is looking for an appropriate method to test his website; I quote: "method for testing my code". I really don't appreciate the instant downvote, whoever did it.

Comment: Sorry about the vague questioning; I think my class kind of confused me. My prof never really went over debugging and error testing aside from just uploading our code and hoping it works. For a class this is fine since no one is looking at the site until you submit the assignment, but about a year removed from the class when I actually tried starting a project I immediately saw the flaw in this.

Comment: Ah yes, this would be detrimental in a professional context. Imagine if Facebook did their development on the production site and suddenly something is gone, all mangled up or breaks your account. It would be a company killer and people would get fired right away.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP, then you really need to check out PHP Unit (https://phpunit.de/).  It's *the* way to unit test your code.  Most professional outfits have a suite of unit tests, or they wish they do.

I see another answer has covered the LAMP/WAMP/MAMP idea - which you should definitely use for local testing of the front-end.